# SQL server identity suppression context

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a Users table, in which I would like to reserve the top 99 ID values for manual-entry system users.  I have set my identity seed to 100, so that all new users will be given a value 100+ in normal behavior.  I found that I can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` to suppress the identity specification and provide an explicit value for this column.  What I need to know, and could not really understand from MSDN, is if this suppression will *only* apply to the context of the running script. (i.e., new users created on the site, calling the normal insert proc, will still be given autogenerated ID of next value > 100)

Comment: I would be inclined to create the table and then load the first 99 rows, marking them as reserved and unused.  A NULL username might be all you need to track unallocated rows.  OTOH, I'm not generally keen on the design.  Most of my systems keep user data in perpetuity so that other historical data makes sense, i.e. who created some other record or authorized some action.  As users disappear their accounts are flagged as inactive.  In this case you would be locked into no more than 99 above average users for all time.  I'd rather assign a limited resource, e.g. speed dial numbers, to users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT` *allows* you to directly insert an identity value, it doesn't *require* it. So, even if it were a shared setting, running your "normal" INSERT would get an auto-generated identity.

That said, it is a per-session setting as well, so you're doubly safe.

As to the design - I've done similar, and don't see an issue with it. Having "well-known" identifiers is fairly common - though you'll have to decide whether 100 is an appropriate block to reserve. Though possible, you really don't want to have to open a non-contiguous block at a later time. I've used negative numbers in the past when there wasn't a reserved range.

Comment: In addition, only one table in a session can have IDENTITY_INSERT at a time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx